# How to download file from url without opening new tab

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to be able to download video in mobile browser when clicking on a link without opening a new tab in the browser.
I have scoured google and tried many cases including setting header, using readfile(Url) but still not working on mobile browser.
let's say my url is:
[video_play](https://v16m-default.akamaized.net/c35937aff786a80493a2cdc2a700cd0c/628508d2/video/tos/maliva/tos-maliva-ve-0068c799-us/ce2000e7cc5141789a8865ba5f4e0c9f/?a=0&ch=0&cr=0&dr=0&lr=all&cd=0%7C0%7C0%7C0&cv=1&br=5004&bt=2502&cs=0&ds=6&ft=L4cJSoTzDJhNvyBiZqBaRfG9t7pBO5VxFNp2z7&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=aWVlPDtoaGY0OGc1NDk1M0BpanFkMzU6Znc1OzMzZzczNEBjLjA1NmIzXjIxNl8vYWE1YSNwaWNwcjRfcnFgLS1kMS9zcw%3D%3D&l=202205180854330101921662190422692C)
my php code:

```
header('Content-Type: ' . $mContentType);
header('Content-Length: ' . $mContentLength);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=" . "'" . $file_name . "'");
flush();
readfile($Url);
exit();
```

Comment: Do you want to _download_ the video file or _view_ the video?

Comment: I want to download video on client side, currently I am attaching the link to <a href="url">Download Video</a> tag but when clicking on the tag the browser will open a new tab and play the video